# Do you need help vs do you need any help

Tags: phrase-usage

Is there a difference between thses two sentences?

> Do you need help (studying for the test)?

vs

> Do you need any help (studying for the test)?

I wonder if they can be interchangeable when I want to help someone study for a test.

Comment: There's no practical difference between the two; you can use either and be understood perfectly well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference between the two.  Both

> Do you need help studying for the test?

and

> Do you need any help studying for the test?

Are completely the same thing and are totally interchangeable.

Comment: OK! I thought that "help" without "any" might refer to something more specific or something.

Comment: @jess: Usually adding any to a statement will make it more broad.  In this case though, help is an already broad topic so it doesn't change the meaning in any tangible way.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point out that different sentences like this can have convey nuances of communication outside the main idea, related to social relationship, interaction, emotional intelligence, etc.

(**Bold text below** marks parallel constructions; it is not intended as verbal emphasis.)

- Do you **need help** studying for the test?

  This is a little abrupt. Imagine a person behind a desk that reads (silently) from a checklist, "Needs help studying for test:  Yes/No" and then asks the question above.  This form of question would occur more often from someone direct, sharp, not interested in actually giving help, or someone very logically minded.
- Do you **need some help** studying for the test?

  As a rule of thumb, more words are "softer", "nicer", or "more polite".  "Some" may indicate a non-trivial amount
  of time, such as a willingness (or desire) from the asking person to spend time 
  with the person.  This perspective might be emphasized as, "**Would you like some help**
  studying for the test?"
- Do you **need any help** studying for the test?  "Any" is the broadest and most open-ended sense of help which frees the other person to ask anything.  "No, but do you know a good website for this?"  Or they might consider it an open ended offer without a time limit.

**Note:** The above scenarios are only possible meanings which are highly dependent on context.  I'm not suggesting any of the above should be considered valid for all contexts.  I'm just pointing out the general idea that filler words can soften the question and perhaps make you seem more friendly or polite (yet less direct).